# why item in an number array is string when using for loop?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have very simple typescript code, just to iterate over an array of numbers:

```
const myTable = {};

// data is typed to 'number[]'
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

// item is typed to 'string'
for(const item in data) {
    // compiler error due to item is string type
    myTable[item%2] = true;
}
```

Why typescript type `item` to `string` instead of `number` when it knows `data` is `number[]`?

Comment: `item` is not an item from the array. It's a *key*. And keys are always strings (or symbols). `for...in` iterates over the keys of the object, `for...of` iterates over the values of array.

Comment: when you say key do you mean index? I get confused by the terms now.

Comment: mytable will not accept number as it's key,

Comment: @user842225 Arrays are objects, so indexes of arrays are still just object keys.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the comments.  I am fine either close this or someone makes an answer I will accept.

Comment: BTW, `if...in` is referring to value right?

Comment: What do you mean by `if...in`? There is no such language construct in JS/TS, `for...in` is an actual thing like `for (const x in obj)`. If you mean `if (x in obj)` that's the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) which will return a boolean of whether or not `x` exists as a key in `obj` or up its prototype chain.

Comment: I mean `if(value in hashtable)`, sorry that I was thinking not array.